# mysql query works in phpmyadmin but errors in php

Tags: php, mysql

The following query works fine in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'SELECT `formSubmissionDetails`.formSubmissionId', GROUP_CONCAT('
     ,    `t_', REPLACE(fieldName, '`', '``'), '`.fieldValue
         AS `', REPLACE(fieldName, '`', '``'), '`'
     SEPARATOR ''),
 ' FROM `formSubmissionDetails` ', GROUP_CONCAT('
     LEFT JOIN `formSubmissionDetails`   AS `t_', REPLACE(fieldName, '`', '``'), '`
            ON `formSubmissionDetails`.formSubmissionId = `t_', REPLACE(fieldName, '`', '``'), '`.formSubmissionId
           AND `t_', REPLACE(fieldName, '`', '``'), '`.fieldName = ', QUOTE(fieldName)
     SEPARATOR ''),
 ' GROUP BY `formSubmissionDetails`.formSubmissionId'
) INTO @qry FROM (SELECT DISTINCT fieldName FROM `formSubmissionDetails`) t;

PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

I get the following error from mysqli when attempting to run it via php:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'PREPARE stmt FROM @qry; EXECUTE stmt' at line 9

Here is a working sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/803ee/1

I'm just really stumped.

Comment: Check your ' placing i.e. 'SELECT `formSubmissionDetails`.formSubmissionId' is the actual string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL query that results in several columns all with the same name isn't a good idea. Try this query construct perhaps:

```
select
  `formSubmissionId`
  , max(case when `fieldName` = 'timezone'  then `fieldValue` end) as timezone
  , max(case when `fieldName` = 'language'  then `fieldValue` end) as language
  , max(case when `fieldName` = 'country'   then `fieldValue` end) as country
  , max(case when `fieldName` = 'something' then `fieldValue` end) as something
from `formSubmissionDetails`
group by `formSubmissionId`
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/803ee/5

which produces:

```
| formSubmissionId |      timezone | language | country | something |
|------------------|---------------|----------|---------|-----------|
|                0 | Europe/London |       en |      45 |         x |
|                1 |  Europe/Paris |       fr |      46 |    (null) |
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that my columns are dynamic.

Comment: so make it dynamic, the sql structure remains the same, just plug in the various names at the various locations of that sql